# GM_addValueChangeListener example

Tags: tampermonkey

I haven't been able to find any GM_`addValueChangeListener` examples on the web. I would like to add a simple listener for Chrome (Tampermonkey) to see if a GM value has been set. If not chrome I set an interval instead.

```
if (!!window.chrome && window.navigator.vendor === "Google Inc."){ 
    console.log("GM_addValueChangeListener supported.");
    GM_addValueChangeListener(name, update);
    function update(name, old_value, new_value, from_remote) {
       console.log(arguments);    
        if( getStorage() ) {  //gets GM stored data
            //update fields
            removeStorage(); //removes GM stored data
        } else alert("No data exported.");
    }
} else {
    console.log("not chrome, using setInterval");
    setInterval(function(){ 
        if( getStorage() ) {  //gets GM stored data
            //update fields
            removeStorage(); //removes GM stored data
        } else console.log("no data yet...")
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem and what is the value of `name` in `GM_addValueChangeListener(name, update);` line?

Comment: @wOxxOm the name is TASK and the value is a string.
example: "TASK1111111"
I want an event to trigger when 'GM_setValue("TASK1111111", TASK);' is run.

Comment: sorry, 
var task = "TASK1111111";
GM_setValue("TASK", task);

Comment: Just tried [a simple example](https://puu.sh/kRhdG/684e944950.txt) here and it works, so what's the problem? Have you forgot to declare `// @grant GM_addValueChangeListener` and `// @grant GM_setValue`?

Comment: This worked, thanks.
GM_addValueChangeListener("abc", function() { console.log(arguments) });
I was trying to pass extra arguments into the function and that was causing it to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test GM_addValueChangeListener
// @grant        GM_addValueChangeListener
// @grant        GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addValueChangeListener("abc", function() { console.log(arguments) });
GM_setValue("abc",123);
```